# Send Email to Stop a job

Tags: sql-server, jobs

is it possible to stop a running job on sql server by sending an email?

Comment: Have the thing/person/system that would send your notional email connect to the db (or invoke something that does) and stop the job.

Comment: SQL Server can't be "stopped" by sending an email no.

Comment: SQL server  can actually generate Email, it doesn't accept. You should configure inbound email which then should insert contents into a table. Configure to stop the job based on the count on table and inserted date. So the answer is no, it doesn't directly stop the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two solution:

1-  Write a function in C# which check the email and convert it to DLL and you should add this assembly to SQL and use it as job for every 1 minute for example.

2-  Using SSIS

Comment: please share the ssis process.

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible :)  However there is no native solution.

You could write a program in another language (like Python, .NET, etc.) and monitors an email inbox.  If said email shows up, it can run the proper SQL to stop the job which would be:

```
sp_stop_job   
  [@job_name =] 'job_name'  
| [@job_id =] job_id   
| [@originating_server =] 'master_server'  
| [@server_name =] 'target_server'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-stop-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017